# Java Garbage collection log gets truncated when the tomcat is stopped

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

I start tomcat process with the following options

```
JAVA_OPTS = "-Xloggc:/put/logs/here/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
```

When I stop tomcat, my `gc.log` file gets truncated and I lose all the data. The file size doesn't change. It just has the information of the heap just before the the process was stopped.

Any pointer on how to retain the garbage collection details even after stopping tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=<number of files> -XX:GCLogFileSize=<size>
```

where number of files is just an integer and size is the size of the file (e.g 16K is 16 kilobytes, 128M is 128 megabytes, etc.)

Above command can help you with the same, for more visit [this](http://jyates.github.io/2012/11/05/rolling-java-gc-logs.html)

Comment: That is just for rotating the logs file. It doesn't solve the problem of the gc.log file getting truncated and losing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Tocmat stop script launches JVM process to send stop signal.
It is using same JAVA_OPTS for `gc.log` file gets overridden.

Do not add `-Xloggc` in JAVA_OPTS.

If you you really need to redirect GC logs from Tomcat to separate file modify JVM launch command in Tomcat scripts.

If you need quick workaround you can add time stamp to log file path for `-Xloggc` in JAVA_OPTS.